# Challenge and Authentication Schemes not found for Azure AD Authentication with dotnet Core Web MVC app

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I am creating an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC web app and try to set up Azure AD authentication (on my Mac using Visual Studio for Mac). I believe I did everything necessary to set up AD authentication in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
                o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
                .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                .AddCookie();
```

I make sure I use the middleware:

```
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

When the app pops up in chrome browser, I got the following error:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.**

> InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).

My code shows both authenticationScheme and DefaultChallengeScheme setup, not sure why it cannot find those two schemes. anyone knows?

**Nuget versions:**

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication (2.2.0)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AzureAD.UI (3.1.2)

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (3.1.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your codes to :

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));
```

`AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` will be used by default when a specific scheme isn't requested.

Also modify the middleware order :

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

To make sure the authentication middleware fires before authorization middleware .

Answer (score 1):

As you are using [OpenID Connect (OIDC) authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x?view=aspnetcore-3.1#openid-connect-oidc-authentication), so invoke the AddOpenIdConnect method in the ConfigureServices method:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/your_tenantId";
    options.ClientId = "your_clientId";
 });
```

And appsettings.json:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Domain": "xxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "TenantId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
}
```

In your Azure ad application registered, set redirect url with `/signin-oidc`.

[image]