# Microsoft.Identity.Web OpenIdConnect was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authenticated

Tags: azure-active-directory, openid-connect

My app had been working with Microsoft.Identity for the past couple of years and something changed that is causing users to have to clear cache to authenticate. I have verified reply url's, the tenant id, client id and client secret and they all have not changed and are correctly setup. I updated to the latest nuget package. And after clearing browser cache the authentication works perfectly. What could be causing this?

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
        options.HandleSameSiteCookieCompatibility();
    });

    services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(Configuration, "AzureAd");
    //services.AddSignIn(Configuration);
    // Token acquisition service based on MSAL.NET 

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseSession();
    app.UseMiddleware<UserClaims>();
    app.UseAuthorization();
```

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 POST https://localhost:44326/signin-oidc application/x-www-form-urlencoded 3217
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsService: Information: CORS policy execution successful.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: Cookies signed in.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 626.0063ms 302 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request starting HTTP/2.0 GET https://localhost:44326/  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: OpenIdConnect was not authenticated. Failure message: Not authenticated
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService: Information: Authorization failed.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Information: AuthenticationScheme: OpenIdConnect was challenged.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics: Information: Request finished in 225.1113ms 302
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure to add authentication middleware in order that app.UseAuthentication(); comes before  app.UseMvc();

```
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

> **Note** that AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp is using its  own cookie (auth)  provider
> instead using  the existing one (maybe After being upgraded).

Try using by making cookiescheme to null

```
services.AddAuthentication() .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration,"AzureAd", "AzureAD", cookieScheme: null);
```

or
try to explicity add the schemes so that  scheme is able to handles exceptions of  challenge errors  like 401.

For that you may need  to call AddAuthentication() and configure a default challenge schemes something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/secure-app-with-oidc-and-azure-ad/3-create-aad-register-app#:%7E:text=configure%20the%20authentication%20middleware%20in%20the%20Startup.ConfigureServices%20method%3A).

```
services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
```

**NOTE:**  **AddAuthentication()** method actually configures the service to add cookie-based authentication.This cookie used in browser scenarios and also to set the challenge to OpenID Connect.

and  register Microsoft Identity routes with  one call minumum to endpoints.MapControllerRoute() or a call to `endpoints.MapControllers()`.

or

```
services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureAD(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(AzureADDefaults.OpenIdScheme, options =>
    {
        options.Authority = options.Authority + "/v2.0/";
        options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    });
```

Please check [microsoft-identity-web issues in github](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/133#issuecomment-743100247)

**References:**

1. [aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2 (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/4-WebApp-your-API/4-1-MyOrg)
2. [asp.net mvc - IdentityServer4 - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438573/identityserver4-signin-oidc-page-is-redirecting-to-login-page-infinitely)
3. [Stack Overflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60629918/challenge-and-authentication-schemes-not-found-for-azure-ad-authentication-with)

Comment: Thanks for the ideas.  I will try them.  My app.Use statements are in this order.             app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseMiddleware<UserClaims>();
            app.UseAuthorization();

Comment: Unfortunately I tried the 3 ideas above without any success. I spent some time verifying the url to make sure the redirect was correct and everything appears correct.  I don't understand enough to figure out why cookies or cache are causing an authentication failure.